# Is "said unto me" the same thing as "said to myself"?

Tags: meaning

From Myself (Mother Goose rhyme):

> Myself said unto me:
> "Look to thyself,
> Take care of thyself,
> For nobody cares for thee."

Is it an old-fashioned of saying the same thing or is there a little difference between the two? Because I never heard unto being used like that.

Comment: You read it correctly. Note that children’s rhymes often try to imitate the way small children speak, so this is not an example to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**unto**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unto) is an archaic preposition meaning **to**. These days it is only ever seen in old texts, like nursery rhymes (which can be *very* old) or, most commonly, the King James Bible.

So yes, "Myself said unto me" means "I said to myself."

Comment: Good answer. *Unto* does appear in a few fixed phrases that aren’t old quotes, such as “a law unto himself.”